# Berry connection in condensed matter vs. molecular dynamics

Tags: condensed-matter, differential-geometry, solid-state-physics, molecular-dynamics

In principle, a connection is totally arbitrary. Berry connection is not **the** connection, but rather it is simply **a** connection that is physically motivated. That is, mathematically, we could connect the U(1)-principle bundle fibers in any sort of way, but Berry connection is special because it yields physical consequences. This choice is justified in the realm of molecular dynamics through the requirement that the wave function is always an eigenfunction for any trajectory in the parameter space, which is like saying a solution of the time-dependent Schrodinger equation is equivalent to being parallel-transported along any path.

The usual derivation assigns time dependence to the parameters of the Hamiltonian. For example, for an $H_2$ molecule, we allow the interatomic distance to be a function of time, $R=R(t)$ and insist that as we vary $t$ the resulting wave functions continue to be eigen states of the Hamiltonian. From this, we arrive at the Berry connection, $A=-i\psi_R^\dagger \partial_R \psi_R$. Additionally, we **need** a connection in this area of work, because, in solving the Hamiltonian, we need to know what it means to differentiate with respect to the parameter $R$. That is, one frequently encounters equations that include $\nabla_R \psi_R(r)$ which make no sense without a way to connect the various fibers of the $R$-parameter space.

In crystals, the exact same argument to derive Berry connection is used, but I cannot see how it is justified or needed in this setting. The parameter that is given time dependence is the crystal momentum, $k$, which parallel transports $\psi_{k(t)}(r)$ throughout the Brillouin zone. However, this is introduced alongside a time *independent* tight-binding model where the band structure that falls out is likewise time independent. Even still, we insist that we are able to assign a Berry connection to each point of the Brillouin zone. Furthermore, one never encounters $\nabla_k\psi_k(r)$, so it does not seem obvious why one needs a connection anyways.

So my questions are the following:

1. How do we justify the functional dependence of $k$ on time when our theory is independent of time?
2. In a similar vein, how do we justify the use of the time dependent Schrodinger's equation in deriving the Berry connection for the condensed matter setting if $k$ is not actually time dependent?
3. What is the reasoning for defining a connection at all? Or alternatively, where in our theory do we take $\nabla_k\psi(r)_k$?

Of course, I am aware that regardless of the need or method of derivation, Berry connection is related to physics, and we see this over and over again in calculations. Even still, I want to understand what is special about Berry connection in condensed matter that makes it the one connection out of infinite others that is related to physical reality. At the time of writing this, I have not seen the distinction between Berry connection in crystals and molecules discussed, and I was hoping that someone could shed some light on this. Thank you very much for any help.